$[S^n,X]=0\Longrightarrow\pi_n(X,x_0)=0$
Let X be a path connected topological Space, then I want to prove that
$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:[S^n,X]=0\Longrightarrow\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\pi_n(X,x_0)=0
$
Here
$
[S^n,X]:=\{f:S^n\rightarrow X\}/(f\sim g:\Leftrightarrow\exists H:[0,1]\times S^n\rightarrow X\text{ with }H_0=f,H_1=g)
$
and
$\pi_n(X,x_0)=\{f:S^n\rightarrow X:f(1)=x_o\}/(f\sim g:\Leftrightarrow\exists H':[0,1]\times S^n\rightarrow X\text{ with }H'_0=f,H'_1=g,H'_t(1)=x_0\forall t\in [0,1])$
For $n=1$ this makes sense to me:
given the free homotopy $H$ from say $f:S^1\rightarrow X$ to the constant map $\mathrm{const}_{x_0}:S^1\rightarrow X,x\mapsto x_o$. I can construct a new homotopy by precomposing with $H(cxt,1)$, executing my homotopy $H$ and postcomposing with $H(1-cxt,1)$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Already in this case I'm having troubles to formalize the new homotopy $H'$ correctly. I hope you understand my idea. For $n\geq 2$ I'm thinking that the main idea could be similar, but I can't formalize it.
context:
I'm currently working myself through the proof of Kuiper's theorem. The course of action is to first show $[X,GL(H)]=0$ for any compact topological space and then to follow that all homotopy groups vanish.

A construction similar to the one pictured and explained on p. 341 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology might be helpful.

In general, one has the following standard fact:
Proposition. The following are equivalent for a topological space $X$:

$\pi_n(X,x)=0$ for any $x\in X$.
Any continuous map $S^n\rightarrow X$ is freely nullhomotopic, which means exactly $[S^n,X]=0$, with your notation.
Any continuous map $S^n\rightarrow X$ may be extended to a continuous map $D^{n+1}\rightarrow X$ on the disk.

Proof. Use the notation $I=[0,1]$. That the first statement implies the second one is clear.
Now assume the second one and let $f:S^n\rightarrow X$. Then we have a homotopy $h:S^n\times I\rightarrow X$ with $h_0=c_p$ and $h_1=f$, where $c_p$ is the constant map $S^n\rightarrow X$ mapping every $s\in S^n$ to some $p\in X$. Now observe that collapsing the subset $S^n\times\{0\}$ of $S^n\times I$ to a point yields a space which is clearly homeomorphic to $D^{n+1}$ (it is just the cone of $S^n$). Because $h$ is constant on the collapsed subset $S^n\times \{0\}$, the universal property of the quotient yields a continuous map $S^n\times I/S^n\times\{0\}\rightarrow X$. Precomposing this with our homeomorphism $D^{n+1}\cong S^n\times I/S^n\times\{0\}$ yields the extension we are looking for.
Finally, assume the third assertion, and let $[f]\in\pi_n(X,x)$ for some $x\in X$, where $f:(S^n,s_0)\rightarrow (X,x)$ is a continuous pointed map. By assumption, we may extend the map $f$ to a map $F:D^{n+1}\rightarrow X$ on the disk. Consider for any $s\in S^n$ the ray $t\mapsto r_s(t):=(s-s_0)(1-t)+s_0$ joining $s_0$ to $s$ (for $s=s_0$, this is just the constant map to $s_0$). We define the continuous map $h: S^n\times I\rightarrow X$ given by $(s,t)\mapsto F(r_s(t))$. Note that it is well defined because $D^{n+1}$ is convex. Now we see that this is the pointed homotopy that we were seeking, as one readily checks.

This is incredibly elegant and highly useful. Thank you so much! :)
